# Appstore of WSO2 Appmanager or EMM

Tags: wso2

In the current versions of App-manager(1.1.0) and in EMM (2.0.1), there is no such facility to install the application through an application.Means, for installing the application we have to open the store by a URL on internet browser.In the upcoming versions of Appmanager/EMM can we expect a  native app which can be installed on the mobile device,and it will redirect to all the application,just like a play store which android devices provide.Any suggestion will really be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the current versions of App-manager(1.1.0) and in EMM (2.0.1), there is no such facility to install the application through an application.Means, for installing the application we have to open the store by a URL on internet browser.

Yes this is true. Currently EMM/App manager does not have a native application to browser the applications in the app store.

> In the upcoming versions of app manager/EMM can we expect a native app which can be installed on the mobile device,and it will redirect to all the application,just like a play store which android devices provide.Any suggestion will really be helpful.

Yes, a native app for browsing and installing/uninstalling apps on a device will be available[1] in EMM 2.1.0 which is the upcomming version of WSO2 EMM. However, this will only be available for Android platform in EMM 2.1.0. You can build this application using Android studio[2] and use it with EMM 2.1.0. As for iOS and Windows platforms, if you wish to build an app catalog app your-self, you can refer the Android source code[2] and the swagger definitions of app manager's publisher[3] and store[1].

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/App+Catalog+Application+for+Android+Devices
2. https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/tree/master/modules/mobile-agents/android/app-catalog
3. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-appmgt/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.rest.api.util/src/main/resources/publisher-api.json
4. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-appmgt/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.rest.api.util/src/main/resources/store-api.json